# Why App Getting Rejected due UIBackgrounds Modes Key?

Tags: audio, appstore-approval

My App has done in Titanium.My App has some audio mp3 links in some section.User can play that links and for playing it in background i have added the a key **Required background modes** as "App plays audio".But Apple rejecting my two times even though i am using audible content and Providing the key in **Info.Plist** -Please someone suggest what should i do?Do i need to upload the new build again on Itunes?
[image]

> **2.16: Multitasking apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc.**
>
> We found that your app uses a background mode but does not include functionality that requires that mode to run persistently. This behavior is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> We noticed your app declares support for audio in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist, but did not include features that require persistent audio.
>
> As indicated in the iOS Application Programming Guide:
>
> "This key is intended for use by applications that provide audible content to the user >while in the background, such as music-player or streaming-audio applications."
>
> Therefore, it would be appropriate to provide audible content to the user while the app is in the background or remove the "audio" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key.
>
> For discrete code-level questions, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. Please be sure to:
>
> - include the complete details of your rejection issues
> - prepare any symbolicated crash logs, screenshots, and steps to reproduce the issues for when the DTS engineer follows up.
>
> For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please see Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application Crash Reports.
>
> If you have difficulty reproducing this issue, please try testing the workflow as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/Testing Workflow with Xcode's Archive feature".

Comment: This issue is resolved now.I am happy.My App is live now.I just add a notes and inform the reviewer that where exactly sound file for playing and they approved the My App.Nothing was wrong in my code.They skipped that section while reviewing.

Comment: i also got same problem, is it enough to explain the conditions in the Description column while uploading to appstore again? please suggest me as early as possible?

Comment: In my case they were not able to reach which section was playing the audio so you just tell them with help path by which they can get that audio section.No need to upload the build you just comment like that.

Comment: Thank you very much to respond, i will do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should set appropiate audio session in your AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method to support background music playing.

```
[[AVAudioSession shareInstance] setDelegate:self];
NSError *sessionError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession shareInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];

NSError *activationError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession shareInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationError];
```